# Spawn child_process on directory

Tags: node.js

How to spawn this command (/usr/bin/which flac) on node.js:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cmd = spawn('/usr/bin/which flac', parameters);
```

I've tried that code but its not working, assuming that parameters variables are set.

Comment: Since your code seems to be taken from [here](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), don't forget the semi-colon at the end of line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `flac` needs to be passed as a parameter. Try this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cmd = spawn('/usr/bin/which', ['flac'], {detached:true, stdio: 'inherit'})
.on('exit',function(code){
  //check exit code
});
```

For example, running the same code with `node` instead of `flac` gives:

```
/usr/bin/node
```